# NSDate question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

I am calculating the months differences between two dates using :

```
NSInteger month = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate: start toDate: end options: 0] month];
```

When it calculates the months, i am having a small issue. Lets assume that :

startdate = 01/05/2005; (dd/mm/yyyy)
enddate = 01/06/2005; (dd/mm/yyyy)

Month difference is returned as 0. I noticed that to return the correct result (in this instance being 1) , i need to set the enddate to +1days of the start date. So, 02/06/2005. How could i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the timeZone to UTC.

Here's example code that returns 1 for the difference.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSDate * start = [formatter dateFromString:@"01/05/2005"];
NSDate * end = [formatter dateFromString:@"01/06/2005"];    

NSInteger month = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate: start toDate: end options: 0] month];
NSLog(@"%@, %@ --> difference: %d", start, end, month);
```

Answer (score 0):

But the difference is 0 months, as it's the same month. If you prefer to represent the same month as one, and the 'next' month as 2, can you simply add 1 to the result?

Comment: 5 and 6 are not the same month. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your input is being misinterpreted. How are you creating the start and end objects? Have you verified that your input data is being interpreted as dd/mm/yyyy as you intended, rather than mm/dd/yyyy?

If the first component ('01' for both start and end) is being interpreted as the month instead of the day, a difference of 0 would be perfectly correct. Also, and using '02' in the end date would (again, correctly) behave the way you describe if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I haven't given it too much though as to whether it's the best solution:

```
NSDate* dateA; // alloc and init
NSDate* dateB; // alloc and init

NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned int unitFlags = NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *difference= [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate: dateA toDate:dateB  options:0];

double hour = [difference hour];
double minute = [difference minute];
double second = [difference second];
```

My goal here was to ignore anything above hour. That's why I set the NSDayCalendarUnit-flag. If you set the NSMonthCalendarUnit-flag (?), it should provide you with months in total, and not just dateA's month - dateB's month.

Edit: I got this from another thread, but couldn't figure out which, so thank you whoever provided me with this piece of code :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing this, and you should be...

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
NSDate *end = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];  
start = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01-05-2005"];
end = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01-06-2005"];

NSInteger month = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate: start toDate: end options: 0] month];
NSLog(@"%i", month);
```